# Chomsky Normal form removing epsilon transitions

Tags: chomsky-normal-form

I'm working on converting a CFG to Chomsky Normal Form but I'm having some difficulty.

I have this CFG

`A-> BAB|B|epsilon
B -> 00|epsilon`

Ok I add a new start state

`S -> A
A-> BAB|B|epsilon
B -> 00|epsilon`

Then I have to remove epsilon transitions so I start with B

`S -> A
A-> BAB|B|AB|BA|A|epsilon
B -> 00`

How do I then remove the epsilon from A? Can the start have an epsilon in it? And how do I convert A-> A?

Answer (score 0):

You can't convert this grammar to one without ε, and therefore it cannot be written in Chomsky Normal form. This is because all productions can reduce to ε, therefore ε is a valid sentence in the language.